# Component with h() render function with conditional render does not re-render on props change

Tags: vuejs3

I have a component that renders content programatically using the h() function.
The rendering is conditional: it checks the boolean value of a prop and renders one thing or another thing depending on the value.
But when the prop changes (which I can verify using a watcher), the component does not re-generate.

Here is code to show what I have tested:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { h } from 'vue';

    export default defineComponent({
      props: {
        useWrapper: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: true
        }
      },
      setup (props, { slots }) {
    
        watch(() => props.useWrapper, (newValue) => {
          console.log('useWrapper changed: ' + newValue + ' - rerender');
        });
    
        if (!props.useWrapper) {
          return () => h('div', {}, 'Some funny content');
        }
    
        return () => h('div', {}, 'Other content');
      }
    });
    </script>
```

The component does not change when the prop changes, but keeps its first rendering.
Why is that, and how do I make it re-render?

Comment: @tao Any ideas why two returns don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure, but I guess it's component compilation problem.

Simply do not use many returns. Put all inside one and it works as intended.

```js
const { createApp, h, ref, watch } = Vue;

const test = {   
  props: {
        useWrapper: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: true
        }
      },
      setup (props, { slots }) {
    
        watch(() => props.useWrapper, (newValue) => {
          console.log('useWrapper changed: ' + newValue + ' - rerender');
        });
    
        return () => h('div', {}, !props.useWrapper ? 'Some funny content' : 'Other content');
      }
}

const App = {
  components: { 
    test
  },
  setup() {
    return { useWrapper: ref(false) }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>  
  useWrapper: <input type="checkbox" v-model="useWrapper"> ({{useWrapper}})
  <test :use-wrapper="useWrapper"></test>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can 100% do an early return in render functions, but you will have to do it inside the return function itself:

```
import { defineComponent, h, watch } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    useWrapper: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  },
  setup(props,) {
    watch(() => props.useWrapper, (newValue) => {
      console.log('useWrapper changed: ' + newValue + ' - rerender');
    });
  
    return () => {
      if (!props.useWrapper) {
        return h('div', {}, 'Some funny content');
      }
  
      return h('div', {}, 'Other content');
    }
  }
})
```